# List call and Printing, text-based game

Tags: python

So below is my current code for a text based game that I have to finish for a school project:

```
# The dictionary links a room to other rooms as well as listing the item in the room

rooms = {
    "Crew Quarters": {'East': 'Ship Storage', 'South': 'Operations Deck'},
    "Ship Storage": {'West': 'Crew Quarters', 'South': 'Power and Oxygen Control', 'Item': 'Spare O2 Tank'},
    "Operations Deck": {'North': 'Crew Quarters', 'East': 'Power and Oxygen Control',
                        'South': 'Crew Training Chamber', 'West': 'Captain Quarters', 'Item': 'Head Lamp'},
    "Power and Oxygen Control": {'North': 'Ship Storage', 'West': 'Operations Deck',
                                 'South': 'Infirmary'},
    "Captains Quarters": {'East': 'Operations Deck', 'South': 'Armory', 'Item': 'Key to POC'},
    "Armory": {'North': 'Captains Quarters', 'East': 'Crew Training Chamber', 'Item': 'Laser Rifle'},
    "Crew Training Chamber": {'North': 'Operations Deck', 'East': 'Infirmary',
                              'West': 'Armory', 'Item': 'Space Suit'},
    "Infirmary": {'North': 'Power and Oxygen Control', 'West': 'Crew Training Chamber', 'Item': 'Med-kit'}
}
# List of commands for movement or to exit the game
directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
exit_game = ['e', 'exit']
inv = ['inv']
inv_list = []

# Current / starting room
c_room = 'Crew Quarters'

# print the game name, commands, and objectives.
print("Spaceship Text Adventure")
print("There's been a breach in the Power and Oxygen Control room on the ship!",
      "Take care of the threat!")
print("Collect 6 items to defeat the anomaly or let the ship be taken over!")
print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")
print("To check your inventory: 'inv'")
print("To exit the game: 'e' or 'exit'")


# Game Loop
while True:
    print('\nYou are in the', c_room)
    command = input("\nWhere would you like to go? ")
    if command in directions:
        if command in rooms[c_room]:
            c_room = rooms[c_room][command]
            print(c_room)
            # 1
        else:
            print('You cannot go that way')

    elif command in inv:
        print(inv_list)

    elif command in exit_game:
        print('You have exited the game. Thank you for playing!')
        break

    else:
        print('Invalid command, try again!')
```

So what I want/need to do is whenever the player enters a room with an item in it, I need it to display the item that is in that room. If the player already has the item in the inventory, and they go back into the room, i need it to display "You've already taken the item from this room."

Where I placed my #1 is where I feel like the code should go, but I honestly have no idea. Any help would be appreciated as I'm struggling with calling upon lists and printing different statements. TYIA!

Answer (score 0):

In helping out someone else with a similar room navigation game, I had added an inventory list that acquired a copy of the items selected in the various rooms.  Following is the sample code.

```
# data setup
rooms = {'Great Hall': {'name': 'Great Hall', 'item': ['none'], 'south': 'Vendetta Room', 'east': 'Kitchen',
                        'north': 'Potion Lab', 'west': 'Armory',
                        'text': 'You are in the Great Hall.'},
         'Armory': {'name': 'the Armory', 'item': ['Fire Sword'], 'east': 'Great Hall', 'north': 'Treasure Room',
                    'text': 'You are in the Armory.'},
         'Treasure Room': {'name': 'the Treasure Room', 'item': ['Magic Ring'], 'south': 'Armory',
                           'text': 'You are in the Treasure Room.'},
         'Potion Lab': {'name': 'the Potion Lab', 'item': ['Healing Potion'], 'east': 'Bedroom', 'south': 'Great Hall',
                        'text': 'You are in the Potion Lab.'},
         'Bedroom': {'name': 'the Bedroom', 'item': ['Magic Key'], 'west': 'Potion Lab',
                     'text': 'You are in the Bedroom.'},
         'Kitchen': {'name': 'the Kitchen', 'item': ['Sandwich'], 'south': 'Storage', 'west': 'Great Hall',
                     'text': 'You are in the Kitchen.'},
         'Storage': {'name': 'Storage', 'item': ['Shield'], 'east': 'Mystery Room',
                     'text': 'You are in Storage.'},
         'Mystery Room': {'name': 'The Mystery Room', 'item': ['none'], 'west': 'Storage', 'north': 'Kitchen',
                          'text': 'You are in the Mystery Room.'},
         # villain
         'Vendetta Room': {'name': 'the Vendetta Room', 'item': ['none'], 'west': 'Dungeon', 'north': 'Great Hall',
                           'text': 'You are in the Vendetta Room.'},
         # Princess
         'Dungeon': {'name': 'the Dungeon', 'item': ['none'], 'east': 'Vendetta Room',
                     'text': 'You are in the Dungeon.'}
         }
        
directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
add_items  = ['get item']
current_room = rooms['Great Hall']
inventory = []

def status():
    print('-' * 20)
    print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room['name']))
    print('Your current inventory: {}\n'.format(inventory))
    if current_room['item']:
        print('Item in room: {}'.format(', '.join(current_room['item'])))
        print('')
        
# game loop
while True:
    status()
    if current_room['name'] == 'The Mystery Room':
        if ['Magic Key'] not in inventory:
            print("Oh No! As soon as you entered, the doors locked behind you.")
            print("You don't have the Magic Key to open the door and end up trapped forever.")
            print("GAME OVER")
            break
        elif ['Magic Key'] in inventory:
            print("Oh No! As soon as you entered, the doors locked behind you.")
            print("Luckily you found the Magic Key and could unlock the doors to continue your journey.")
    if current_room['name'] == 'the Vendetta Room' and len(inventory) > 5:
        print("You used all your items to defeat King Nox! Proceed to the next room to save the Princess.")
    elif current_room['name'] == 'the Vendetta Room' and len(inventory) < 6:
        print("You have found the Demon King but have no weapons.")
        print("You have been defeated and the Princess has perished.")
        print("GAME OVER")
        break
    elif current_room['name'] == 'the Dungeon':
        print('Congratulations! You have reached the Dungeon and saved the Princess!')
        print("You gave the Princess your healing potion and escorted her to the castle.")
        print("Thank you for playing!")
        break
    
    command = input('Enter Move:')

    # movement
    if command == 'quit':           # Moved this ahead of the directional and acquisition commands
        print('Thanks for playing')
        break
    
    if command in directions:
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
        elif command != add_items:
            # bad movement
            print('Invalid entry. Try again.')

    # adding inventory
    elif command in add_items:
        if current_room['item'] != ['none']:
            if current_room['item'] in inventory:   # No need to acquire an item a second time
                print("You already have this item")
            else:
                inventory.append(current_room['item'])
                print("You acquired : ", current_room['item'])
        elif current_room['item'] == ['none']:
            print("No items to collect in this room")            
    else:
        print('Invalid entry. Try again.')
```

I probably did not need to copy in the whole bit.  Mainly you would want to focus in on the block of code at the end that checks to see if the player has already picked up an item and if so, remind the player that they already possess the item.

Give that a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
# The dictionary links a room to other rooms and provides info if there
# is an item in the room along with its status ('noItm':True means item 
# was already taken): 
rooms = {
    "Crew Quarters"           : {'East' : 'Ship Storage',  
                                 'South': 'Operations Deck',
                                 'noItm':  True},
    "Ship Storage"            : {'West' : 'Crew Quarters', 
                                 'South': 'Power and Oxygen Control', 
                                 'Item' : 'Spare O2 Tank',
                                 'noItm':  False},
    "Operations Deck"         : {'North': 'Crew Quarters', 
                                 'East' : 'Power and Oxygen Control',
                                 'South': 'Crew Training Chamber', 
                                 'West' : 'Captain Quarters', 
                                 'Item' : 'Head Lamp',
                                 'noItm':  False},
    "Power and Oxygen Control": {'North': 'Ship Storage', 
                                 'West' : 'Operations Deck',
                                 'South': 'Infirmary',
                                 'noItm':  True},
    "Captains Quarters"       : {'East' : 'Operations Deck', 
                                 'South': 'Armory', 
                                 'Item' : 'Key to POC',
                                 'noItm':  False},
    "Armory"                  : {'North': 'Captains Quarters', 
                                 'East' : 'Crew Training Chamber', 
                                 'Item' : 'Laser Rifle',
                                 'noItm':  False},
    "Crew Training Chamber"   : {'North': 'Operations Deck', 
                                 'East' : 'Infirmary',
                                 'West' : 'Armory', 
                                 'Item' : 'Space Suit',
                                 'noItm':  False},
    "Infirmary"               : {'North': 'Power and Oxygen Control', 
                                 'West' : 'Crew Training Chamber', 
                                 'Item' : 'Med-kit',
                                 'noItm':  False}
}

# List of commands for movement or to exit the game
directions = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West']
exit_game  = ['e', 'exit', 'q', 'quit']
inv        = ['i', 'inv']
get_item   = ['get']
inv_list   = []

# Current / starting room
c_room = 'Crew Quarters'

# print the game name, commands, and objectives.
print("Spaceship Text Adventure")
print("There's been a breach in the Power and Oxygen Control room on the ship!",
      "Take care of the threat!")
print("Collect 6 items to defeat the anomaly or let the ship be taken over!")
print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")
print("To check your inventory: 'inv'")
print("To exit the game: 'e' or 'exit'")


# Game Loop
while True:
    print('\nYou are in the', c_room)
    command = input("\nWhat would you like to do? ")
    if len(command) >= 2 and command[0:2] == 'go':
        direction = command[3:]
        if direction in directions:
            if direction in rooms[c_room]:
                c_room = rooms[c_room][direction]
                if rooms[c_room]['noItm'] is False: 
                    print(c_room)
                    print(f"There is '{rooms[c_room]['Item']}' in this room.")
                else: 
                    if 'Item' in rooms[c_room]:
                        print("You've already taken the item from this room.")
            else:
                print('You cannot go that way')
    elif len(command) > 10 and command[0:3] in get_item:
        item_in_room = rooms[c_room]['Item'] if 'Item' in rooms[c_room] else None
        item_to_get  = command[5:-1]
        if rooms[c_room]['noItm'] is False and item_to_get == item_in_room: 
            inv_list.append(item_in_room)
            rooms[c_room]['noItm'] = True
            print(f"You have got '{item_in_room}'")
        else: 
            print(f"There is no '{item_to_get}' in this room")  
    elif command in inv:
        print(inv_list)
    elif command in exit_game:
        print('You have exited the game. Thank you for playing!')
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid command, try again!')
```

I have added a new key about the existence of an item to the dictionaries in rooms dictionary allowing to add the code for taking items from a room.